# How can I delete the Yahoo Chrome extension installer?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I have a Windows 7 image that I use for distribution. Somehow, the installer for Yahoo's Chrome extension got installed. That means whenever a user logs in and opens Chrome, the Yahoo Chrome extension gets installed into the browser. Does anyone know where the installer is located so that I can remove it? I don't see anything in the registry and I don't see anything listed in AutoRuns. I have also intentionally installed Acrobat and that too installs an extension into Chrome. That suggests Chrome might have some location where it looks for extensions waiting to be installed. Where might that be?

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry entry under (64-bit Windows) at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions. This contains the identity of the extension and a URL where the extension is to be downloaded from. Once I removed this registry key, it no longer installs itself on new accounts.

Comment: This question still has no **accepted** answer. (You can accept your own answers)>